# MDX error with aggregate

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following query with MDX

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Estimating Accuracy Labour Hours] AS 
    Sum
    (
      CASE 
        WHEN 
              (1
              - 
                  [Measures].[Estimation Difference]
                / 
                  Aggregate
                  (
                    [Measures].[Actual Labour Hours]
                   ,[DISTRICTS D].[District]
                   ,[WORK  D].[Work].[Work  Description]
                  )
              )
            * 100
          > 0 
        THEN 
            (1
            - 
                [Measures].[Estimation Difference]
              / 
                Aggregate
                (
                  [Measures].[Actual Labour Hours]
                 ,[DISTRICTS D].[District]
                 ,[WORK  D].[Work].[Work  Description]
                )
            )
          * 100
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) 
   ,VISIBLE = 1 
   ,ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_ = 'WORK F' ;
```

I got the following error

> MdxScript(TEST) (52, 71) Too many arguments were passed to the
>   AGGREGATE function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2.

How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is easier to understand than most MDX error messages!

You have three arguments in this snippet:

```
Aggregate
   (
         [Measures].[Actual Labour Hours]
        ,[DISTRICTS D].[District]
        ,[WORK  D].[Work].[Work  Description]
   )
```

Here is the MSDN definition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx

> Aggregate(Set_Expression [ ,Numeric_Expression ])

Following this definition, move your Numeric_Expression to the end and the other expressions in front of it:

```
Aggregate
   ( 
        ,[DISTRICTS D].[District]
        ,[WORK  D].[Work].[Work  Description]
        ,[Measures].[Actual Labour Hours]
   )
```

Still should be erroring. You then need to make a tuple set out of the first two arguments:

```
Aggregate
   ( 
        {(
         [DISTRICTS D].[District]
        ,[WORK  D].[Work].[Work  Description]
        )}
        ,[Measures].[Actual Labour Hours]
   )
```

Your error message should now go away.